# Prove set of points where continuous functions meet is non-empty and compact

Tags: continuity, compactness

Given $f,g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous with $f(a)=g(b)\ $  and  $\ f(b)=g(a)$ for $a,b\in \mathbb{R} \ $ and $\ a<b $
I have to prove that: The set $$X = \{x\in [a,b] \ | \ f(x)=g(x)\}$$ is not empty and compact.

I'm not quite sure how to write a formal proof for this yet. I know that using the Intermediate value theorem I get that the image set  $f([a,b])$ is another interval of the form $[\min(f(a),f(b)), \max(f(a),f(b)]$ and because $f(a)=g(b)\ $  and  $f(b)=g(a)$ the image set intervals are going to be the same $f([a,b])=g([a,b])$ so I'm imagining graphically, that the functions do keep equaling  eachother at various points in the graph, though I'm not sure how to prove they meet at the exact same point $f(x)=g(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, the function $f-g$ is continuous too. And $X=(f-g)^{-1}\bigl(\{0\}\bigr)$. So, and since $\{0\}$ is closed, $X$ is a closed subset of $[a,b]$. Since $[a,b]$ is compact, this implies that $X$ is compact. And $X\ne\emptyset$ since $f(a)=g(b)$ and $f(b)=g(a)$, because it follows from this and from the intermediate value theorem that there is some $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=g(c)$, and then $c\in X$.

Comment: It's not correct that $a$ or $b$ must be in $X$, but what is true is that the value of $f-g$ at those two points must straddle $0$, which means (applying the Mean Value Theorem to the continuous function $f-g$) that $X$ must be non-empty.

Comment: @RobertShore Right. I misread it; I read that $f(a)=g(a)$ and that $f(b)=g(b)$.

Comment: Isn't the mean value theorem only applicable if the functions f,g are differentiable and f(b)=f(a), which is true given f-g.

Comment: Yes, but I wrote *intermediate* value theorem in my answer. I suppose that that's what @RobertShore had in mind.

Comment: Is it true, that because $f(a)=f(b)$ the only value lying between these two is $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ themselves? So it must be true that also $f(a)=g(a)$ and $f(b)=g(b)$

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why are you assuming that $f(a)=f(b)$? That's not part of the problem.

Comment: I might have misunderstood what @RobertShore said. I thought the value of $f-g$ at the points a and b must be $0$ , so I thought given, $(f-g)(a) = f(a)-g(a) = f(a) - f(b)$ then that must mean $f(a) = f(b)$. But now I see that he meant getting close to it, so I still finds points in between, I think

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That's correct.  I meant the Intermediate Value Theorem, but wrote the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: @Wolf From $f(a)=g(b), g(a)=f(b),$ we have (f-g)(a)=-(f-g)(b), so either both values are $0$ and $\{a, b \} \subseteq X$, or the values straddle $0$ and the Intermediate Value Theorem guarantees the existence of a zero of the difference function between the two points.